# How to prove $[x^k] \cdot (1+x)^{a+b} = \sum_{j=0}^k{a\choose j}\cdot{b\choose {k-j}}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

$$[x^k] \cdot (1+x)^{a+b} =  \sum_{j=0}^k{a\choose j}\cdot{b\choose {k-j}}$$
where $a,b \in \Bbb R$ and $k \in \Bbb N$. Since, 
$$(1+x)^{a+b} = \sum_{j=0}^{a+b} {a+b\choose j} \cdot x^j$$

so, $\displaystyle[x^k] \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{a+b} {a+b\choose j} \cdot x^j= {{a+b}\choose k}$

How should I proceed from here? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: what does $[x^k]$ mean?

Comment: @Minz It's a common notation for "the $x^k$ coefficient ot".

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$(1+x)^{a+b}=(1+x)^a(1+x)^b=\left(\sum_{j=0}^a\binom ajx^j\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^b\binom bjx^i\right)$$
and extract the coefficient of $x^k$.

Comment: So, I can prove that $${{a+b}\choose k} = \sum_{j=0}^k{a\choose j} \cdot {b\choose {k-j}}$$. I think this should hold true if instead of choose every term had multichoose, as the number counted should be the same. Am I thinking correctly?